# Autosizing doesn't work when loading from XIB after rotating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

In my app I add a view loaded from XIB with `UIViewAutosizingMaskFlexibleWidth` and have the desired result only in one of two cases:

1. Adding subview on portrait, and rotating to landscape, resizes the subview correctly;
2. Adding subview on landscape do not cause the subview to resize its width the way it does when rotating;

Here is the code:

```
viewMenuList = [[MenuListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuListController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
viewMenuList.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
[self.view addSubview:viewMenuList.view];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:viewMenuList.view];
[viewMenuList.view setNeedsLayout];
[viewMenuList.view setNeedsDisplay];
NSLog(@"frame do menu links view %f, %f, %f, %f", self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"frame do menu list view %f, %f, %f, %f", viewMenuList.view.frame.origin.x, viewMenuList.view.frame.origin.y, viewMenuList.view.frame.size.width, viewMenuList.view.frame.size.height);
```

The output in the console is:

```
2010-12-07 16:34:22.552 SlideShow_iPad[19352:207] frame do menu links view 0.000000, 0.000000, 1030.000000, 111.000000
2010-12-07 16:34:22.596 SlideShow_iPad[19352:207] frame do menu list view 0.000000, 0.000000, 768.000000, 109.000000
```

The last line should display an width of 1030, shouldnt it? It does resize to 1030 after rotating to portrait and going back to landscape.

The strangest thing is that I do use the same technic in the superview and worked.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix both Interface Builder and Objective-C code to handle resizing. Remove autoresizingMask and autoresizesSubviews from code and do both only in Interface Builder. You might have conflicting defines now.

**autoresizingMark:** command-3 to view size properties. Check "Autosizing" part, the animation shows pretty nicely how your resizing will look.

**autoresizesSubviews:** command-1 to view drawing properties. There's a checkbox for this.

Comment: The fact is the the actual behavior is correct. The problem is that I misunderstood the definition of autosizing. Autosizing doesnt mean that it should define the frame size at the moment you add a subview.